# php узнать область видимости функции

Tags: php

Есть ли способ узнать какая область видимости у функции внутри одного класса?

```
class Test {

public A {
     <вот тут узнать PUBLIC или PRIVATE у B и C>
}

public B{}
private С{}
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.reflectionmethod.php

Comment: рефлексия...нужна рефлексия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Test {
    public function A($className) {
        $ref = new ReflectionMethod('Test::'.$className);
        return Reflection::getModifierNames($ref->getModifiers());
    }

    public function B() {}
    private function C() {}
}

var_dump(Test::A('B'));
```

Выводит массив со всеми модификаторами.

Проверить можно очень просто: `in_array(Test::A('B'), 'public')` выводит `true`, если метод `Test::B` публичный.